# Is 'Is x open source?' on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I remember I saw this type of questions numerous times, but seems their fate is quite different.

Now some of them are still open:

- [Is Xamarin Open Source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706740)
- [Is JavaFX open source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703220)
- [Is Intel XDK open source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22450430)
- [Is ASP.NET Identity open source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34070706)

But some of them are closed:

- [Is weblogic open source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354950)
- [Is CCTray open source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497865)
- [Is the PMD Eclipse Plugin Open Source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006820)
- [Is C# compiler open source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988514)

The result looks quite inconsistent, so I would like to know, is this type of questions on topic?